# Defining the change in direction due to wind

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, geometry, aircraft

**My question:** Which force vector (A, B, C, or D) represents the APPROXIMATE direction in which the boat is travelling as a consequence of the wind?

**My approach:** I looked for which vector combination would be proper to draw a Triangle of Forces for, and it appears to me that it is Fwind + Fboat + Fd. Is my reasoning correct, or should/could I take another approach?

The same method seems to be applicable to aircraft, since both boats and aircraft travel through fluid, is that true?

Awaiting your valuable opinions!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. This applies to aircraft as well. The resultant force is the vector sum of the propulsive force and the wind.